# Whats the advantage of having API controller in MVC5 application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

ASP.NET Web API provides a RESTful way for the client to call server side API. So the client that is developed using, for example, Angular or purely HTML & jQuery the Web API make sense.
I have an application developed using ASP.NET MVC5.  In MVC5 we have MVC controllers which mainly used for returning Views. However you can also return JSON from MVC controller.

In my application the views are pretty complex, so I don’t construct the whole model on first view load. Instead I make ajax call using jQuery and get the JSON data as needed. *(Note im using telerik controls which makes the ajax call to get the JSON data).* Regardless who makes the ajax call, throughout my application I have several ajax call to the server. For all these ajax calls I did not create separate API controller using System.Web.Http.ApiController. Instead i am using MVC controller class. So my typical controller class looks like below:

```
        public class HelloWorldController : Controller
            {
                public ActionResult Index()
                {
                    var model = new MyModel();

                    model.populateModelWithSomeBasicData();

                    return View(model);
                }

                [HttpGet]
                public ActionResult GetStates()
                {
                    var result = DomainService.GetStatesFromDB();

                    var model = ConvertToModel(result);

                    return Json(model);
                }

                [HttpGet]
                public ActionResult GetUsers(string stateCode)
                {
                    var result = DomainService.GetUsersFromDB(stateCode);

                    var model = ConvertToModel(result);

                    return Json(model);
                }

                [HttpPost]
                public ActionResult ActivateUser(int userID)
                {
                    var result = DomainService.ActivateUser(userID);

                    var model = ConvertToModel(result);

                    return Json(model);
                }

                [HttpPost]
                public ActionResult DeActivateUser(int userID)
                {
                    var result = DomainService.DeActivateUser(userID);

                    var model = ConvertToModel(result);

                    return Json(model);
                }

                [HttpPost]
                public ActionResult Save(MyModel model)
                {
                    var entity = ConvertToDomainEntity(model)
                    DomainService.Save(entity);
                    return View('MyView',model);
                }
            }
```

**Question**
1> Is it okay to combine Action Methods which returns Views and JSON data into one System.Web.Mvc.Controller? I don’t see any advantage having separate API controller just to return JSON? In-fact in MVC6 Microsoft got rid of api controller and in MVC6 one controller serves both the purposes.

2>I have some buttons on the page like activate user, deactivate user for which i dont have to send whole model to the sever. The action methods takes ID as parameter. (in this case i use jquery to make http post) Is okay to have such methods in Mvc Controller?

Technically the way i have the controller is working, my question is related to recommended design practice

Comment: MVC wasn't really designed with REST-ful semantics in place. WebAPI was. If you need a service layer, you should use WebAPI... for rendered views you should use MVC. There are a lot of features in webAPI that simply make working with any kind of restful API layer much nicer. The decision is ultimately yours, but I wouldn't mix the two concerns together. *All my own opinion of course*

Comment: @Josh Thanks. What nicer feature are there in APIcontroller that are not in MVC controller? i just need to GET and POST data to server.